# sizeof std::aligned_storage and std::aligned_union

Tags: c++, c++11, sizeof, type-traits

Given the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

int main() {
    std::aligned_storage<sizeof(double), alignof(double)> storage;
    std::aligned_union<sizeof(double), double> union_storage;
    std::cout << sizeof(storage) << '\n';
    std::cout << sizeof(union_storage) << '\n';
    std::cout << sizeof(double) << '\n';
}
```

I expect `sizeof(storage)` and `sizeof(union_storage)` to be greater or equal to `sizeof(double)` since they have to be able to hold a `double`. However, [I get the output](https://ideone.com/9PbVwI)

```
1
1
8
```

clang-3.8 and gcc-5.3 both produce this output.
Why does `sizeof` return an incorrect size?
If I use placement new to put a `double` into `storage` or `union_storage` would that be undefined behavior?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`std::aligned_storage` and `std::aligned_union` are type traits which  provide a member `type` which is the actual type of the storage.
Thus, placing a double in the memory of the actual trait type would indeed be UB because they're empty types with just a typedef member.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

int main() 
{
    using storage_type = 
        std::aligned_storage<sizeof(double), alignof(double)>::type;
    using union_storage_type =
        std::aligned_union<sizeof(double), double>::type;

    storage_type storage;
    union_storage_type union_storage;

    std::cout << sizeof(storage_type) << '\n';
    std::cout << sizeof(union_storage_type) << '\n';
    std::cout << sizeof(storage) << '\n';
    std::cout << sizeof(union_storage) << '\n';
    std::cout << sizeof(double) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

[This gives](http://ideone.com/erZDp7):

```
8
8
8
8
8
```

Note: As @T.C. correctly noted: C++14 provides alias templates ending on `_t` for the `std` type traits (i.e. `std::aligned_storage<L, A>::type === std::aligned_storage_t<L,A>`). The benefit is

1. No `typename` in template dependant context.
2. Less typing. ;)

Comment: Or `aligned_storage_t` etc. in C++14.